# Which one would be better?

Tags: meaning, word-order, sentence-usage

Is it grammatically correct to say “We went to the movies Yesterday”?
Or would it sound better to say “Yesterday we went to the movies”?

For example, I know that it sounds odd to say “It was a good day Yesterday”. On the other hand, saying “Yesterday was a good day” sounds more natural. 
Why is that?

Comment: All four sentences are natural and idiomatic. (Your third sentence doesn't sound odd at all.) The only thing unusual is that you are capitalizing *Yesterday* when it's not at the start of the sentence.

Comment: Why capitalize yesterday??

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence

> We went to the movies Yesterday

Yesterday serves as an adverb, it describes when "We went"

In the sentence

> Yesterday was a good day

Yesterday is the subject of the sentence.